# BASH - Run 6 scripts but only 3 togheter at a time and if one is finished then start with another

Tags: bash

.

I have a simple bash script where i run 3 at the same time and when they are done they start with the next 3 like this:

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
wait
command4 &
command5 &
command6 &
exit
```

But how can i do so i always run 3 of these at the same time and not wait for the other three? lets say command1 and command2 finished but command3 still runnin, then i want command4 and command5 to start so there is always 3 commands running.

Thanks

Comment: With current GNU xargs: Put your commands in a text file. Each command in a separate line and then execute the following: `xargs -n 1 -P 3 -I {} bash -c {} < file_with_commands`

Comment: I tried using this:

    max_jobs=3
    declare -A cur_jobs=( ) # build an associative array w/ PIDs of jobs we 
    started
    for ((i=0; i<6; i++)); do
    if (( ${#cur_jobs[@]} >= max_jobs )); then
    wait -n # wait for at least one job to exit
    # ...and then remove any jobs that aren't running from the table
    for pid in "${!cur_jobs[@]}"; do
    kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null && unset cur_jobs[$pid]
    done
    fi
    ./j"$i" & cur_jobs[$!]=1done
    wait


But how can i specify the dir? command1 and command2 for example have different locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` 4.3 introduced a `-n` option to `wait`, which lets you wait for the next job to complete.

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
wait -n
command4 &
wait -n
command5 &
wait -n
command6 &
exit
```

Comment: Perhaps you might move this answer to the flagged-duplicate question?